# How do I integrate popToRootViewControllerAnimated with my tabs?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I am trying to make one of my tab buttons go to the root using popToRootViewControllerAnimated. My question is: where do I put this code for it to work? I have my tabs created through Interface Builder... do they have to be hard coded for this to work?

Here is the code that I'm looking to use:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

New code in AppDelegate:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (viewController = HomeViewController) {
        [HomeViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adam - I ended up ditching the subclass idea even though it worked, as there is a much easier method.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        [(UINavigationController*)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

This is the code required. I've uploaded [this sample project](http://www.mackross.net/?attachment_id=91) to play around with. The main points are

- the UITabBarController delegate must
  be set to the App Delegate.
- the App
  Delegate must implement the `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>` protocol.
- the App Delegate must
  implement the code above.

The sample project also shows one way to selectively choose which navigation controllers this occurs with.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much mackross. I appreciate the dedication through the past few weeks. I owe you.

Comment: Excellent! This is better than other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this needs to be hardcoded.

If you're using a UITabBarController (I assume you probably are) you'll need to subclass it and override. This will try pop to the root view controller of each navigation controller on a tab. If the root view of a tab item is not a navigation item you will get an exception though.

```
@interface MyTabBarControllerSubClass : UITabBarController {
}
@end
@implementation MyTabBarControllerSubClass
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    [super tabBar:tabBar didSelectItem:item];
    [(UINavigationController*)self.selectedViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

Don't forget to select your subclass in IB :-)

You could also make something a UITabBarControllerDelegate. Though it would probably be harder to implement.

Comment: Is there a global location I can put this in for all of my tabs? Or do I have to do this in each implementation file?

Comment: Scratch that... I'm putting it in my AppDelegate file. Although.. I'm running into errors: "Expected Expression before 'HomeViewController'" and "'HomeViewController' may not respond to '+popToRootViewControllerAnimated:'".... I've updated my code in the original answer. Thanks!

Comment: No it goes in the UITabBarController subclass.

Comment: ie. make a new class that inherits from UITabBarController I've updated my code to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks so much! Once the new class is added, how does this link to the current tab bar? Do I #import the header file into each class?

Comment: In interface builder select the tab bar view controller (not tab bar) and in the inspector change the class to MyTabBarControllerSubclass

Comment: Ps if your still having trouble, let me know and I'll show you over Skype

Comment: Mackross -- Thanks for all of your help. I added a subclass and changed the view in IB... but now when I select a tab, my app crashes.

Comment: Crash Details:  -[MyTabBarControllerSubClass tabBar:didSelectItem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7551e80  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyTabBarControllerSubClass tabBar:didSelectItem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7551e80'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: Sorry, I've had a busy new year and I've not been on stackoverflow. try removing [super tabBar:tabBar didSelectItem:item];

Comment: If you still have trouble I send you a copy of the test project I used.

Comment: mackross -- thanks so much for your help... unfortunately, it is still crashing. Would you mind sending your test project? I really appreciate it.

Comment: I've posted a new answer after doing a bit more investigating.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but for me on Xcode 6 with Swift this solution did not work out. It seems even if `didSelectViewController` is called, `popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)` is not.

I found that calling `shouldSelectViewController` instead works fine for me:

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(UINavigationController) {
        (viewController as UINavigationController).popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
        return true
    }
    return true
}
```

Not sure though if it is a good approach.