# How do i reset my tab to default view?

Tags: ios, uikit, view

I have `UITabViewController` running with `UINavigationController`. In each tab i have a different `TableView`s that are roots of my application tree.

When i click an item of table, it goes to next level viewing another, detailed `TableView`, still having `TabBar` and `NavigationBar` on screen. It works perfectly, except for one thing. If i'm viewing details in one tab, then switch to another tab, and go back again, then i still see my detail. What i want to achieve, is to reset tab after leaving it.

I expect that i have to put something in `viewDidUnload` or simmilar, but couldn't find the right solution.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

do

```
[viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

That will navigate the tab's view controller to the root view whenever the tab is selected.

That's completely OK to keep your main window view controller (tab bar controller) instance at application delegate.

What you need to add is to set the delegate or whatever other initialized class to be the tab bar controller's delegate like this:

```
myTabBarController = [UITabBarController alloc ...
myTabBarController.delegate = self; // the app delegate will be also the tab bar delegate
```

in the app delegate, then you add the following method to the app delegate:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The tab bar controller will call this method whenever it's tab is selected.
You will also want to make the application delegate confirm `UITabBarControllerDelegate` this way:

```
@interface PSAppDelegate : UIResponder <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

that will let the compiler know that app delegate must or might have the methods declared in the protocol and will also give you so convenient auto-complition of this method.

Comment: It does nothing, but maybe i need to define which view is a root one? If yes - how do i do that? P.S. `popToRootViewController` is undefined, i used `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)`

Comment: @cyborg86pl Thanks for edit. Are you sure you have the `UINavigationController` as tabs controllers ? The method `didSelectViewController` must be placed at the tab bar delegate class, check the method is called. The `navigationController` property gives you the nav controller which was the view controller pushed  to, that said the code should work just fine if the tab bar delegate is used and you have the `UINavigationController` tabs controllers.

Comment: I'm new to iOS so it seems i have my problem located deeper in my code. I put `UITabBarController` in my AppDelegate programmatically. Do i need to put your code in AppDelegate implementation or somewhere else? I'm confused right now... Also tried [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487718/how-do-i-integrate-poptorootviewcontrolleranimated-with-my-tabs?answertab=active#tab-top) but it's still not enough...

Comment: I found missing elements, so thanks, nevertheless there is still a bug somewhere in my code. `PSAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];` now shows an incompatibility issue. Hope this would be the last step to fix that.

Comment: @cyborg86pl did you make changes to PSAppDelegate header file as shown in the bottom of the answer ? You need to write <UITabBarControllerDelegate> to avoid the warning which is by the way only informative and doesn't make your app not to run or compile. However that's absolutely preferred to avoid the warnings, that's will be quite obvious and I'm glad you already understand it.

Comment: I made 2 things after your correction - the header one, that you ask about, and `tbc.delegate = self;` which i didn't have. i believe that there is nothing what you posted that i could miss. Rooting tabs still doesn't work, and that warning i pasted is now the only point that xcode asks me about. App runs, but still in the same way. It's really frustrating, i'm out of ideas... fighting with that from yesterday.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13802/discussion-between-cyborg86pl-and-a-live)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to get the view controllers associated with the tabviewcontroller and then create new objects.

self.tabBarController?.viewControllers! will get an array of viewControllers for the tab bar.  In my case they are a UINavigationControllers but they could be anything.  I then get the viewController associated with that and reset that.

If you don't have navigation controllers you can just create new view controller objects and go with that.

below is the solution in my case (with the navcontroller)

```
 let vc = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
    let newVC = YourViewControllerClass()
    vc.viewControllers[0] = newVC as UIViewController
```

This replaces the old (populated) vc with a new one!